# Authoring XACML 3.0 obligations with the ALFA plugin for Eclipse

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, alfa

I have an `XACML` request with two `(resource:type)` attributes and one `(resource:id)` attribute:

```
    <Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os" >  
    <Resource>
        <Attribute AttributeId="resource:type" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            <AttributeValue>status</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>  
        <Attribute AttributeId="resource:type" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            <AttributeValue>pressure</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>  
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">  
            <AttributeValue>status:of:nariman</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Resource>  
    <Subject>
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            <AttributeValue>1111</AttributeValue> 
        </Attribute>
    </Subject>  
    <Action>
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id">
            <AttributeValue>view</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Action>
</Request>
```

I would like to define an obligation with three obligation expressions corresponding to each of the above resource attributes. How do I do that with `ALFA`?

Comment: Just a clarification. I would like to later process my obligation in code by reading the values from each assignment expression and performing further logic (written at the PEP level).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do note your XACML request is actually a XACML 2.0 request whereas ALFA outputs a XACML 3.0 set of policies. So you'll have a version mismatch.

Secondly, in ALFA to build an obligation that would contain your two attributes, you would do the following:

```
namespace stackoverflow{

    attribute subjectId{
        category = subjectCat
        id = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
        type = string
    }

    attribute resourceId{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"
        type = string

    }

    attribute resourceType{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "resource:type"
        type = string

    }

    attribute actionId{
        category = actionCat
        id = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
        type = string
    }

    obligation displayAttributes = "obligation.displayAttributes"

    policy example{
        apply firstApplicable
        rule example{
            permit
            on permit{
                obligation displayAttributes{
                    subjectId = subjectId
                    resourceId = resourceId
                    resourceType = resourceType
                    actionId = actionId
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, it seems your XACML request has a semantic error. What is the English equivalent? Right now you're asking:

> Can user *1111* do the action *view* on either of *status* or *pressure* for
>   resource with id *status:of:nariman*?

You would typically want to ask for pressure and then for status independently or as a multiple request.

Comment: Thank you. I actually intentionally need more than one resource:type attributes in one request. To give more context to the problem, I (as a subject) would like to submit a query that asks for more than one property (status, pressure) of one patient who is nariman in this case. I have a database schema that relates nariman to her properties in a one to many relation.

Comment: So in the above example, does the line: resourceType=resourceType take care of all the resourseType attributes? or do we need to add separate assignment expressions for each?

Comment: It takes care of all the values. The reason is that by default all attributes in XACML are in fact bags of values.